# Cordova Multi-page App window object not working on second page

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

On a single page app if I call

```
console.log("window height = " + window.innerHeight);
```

everything works fine. If I then go to another page through an "a" tag. wait for the device ready and call the same line of code nothing happens. In fact it seems like none of the plugins work. I get no console messages before or after that line of code. If I remove that line then all the console messages start working again.

This all seemed to start after upgrading to cordova 3.4

After that I was able to get the hello world program working. I was getting debug messages. However after I add the following they stop on the second page. but I have simplified it to any call to window.

```
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
} else // Internet Explorer
{
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
}
```

I am working on a mac. After doing a cordova build iOS I am going into the platforms folder and opening the ios project in xCode and running it from their on my device.

Thanks

Leo

Comment: From which version have you upgraded? If migrating from another 3.x, have you removed the plugins before reinstalling them?

Comment: Yes from another version of 3.x. no I have not removed the plugins and re-installed them.  I was getting the problem on a brand new hello world app. I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: So not sure what to say seems like problem is between chair and keyboard.I created a new app from scratch added in all the plugins and this time it seems to be working. Don't know what I did differently this time.

Comment: OK I think I have narrowed this down. window object does not work on a multipage app. I'll update the question.